# How to launch Android app from already opened activity with appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I have two test cases :-

Test case 1:- Login with credentials on android app  and arrived on home screen.

Test case 2:- When I launch the app, home page should be displayed without asking the login screen .

Problem:-When I am executing the appium script it launch the app with login screen and arrive at home screen .but when I again execute the script with test case2 it again launch from the login screen .I am already using No Reset option.

I need that it should be launched from home screen activity.Whenever I will get the error on some activity it should be launch on the same activity not from the beginning.

Actually problem is when i run appium capabilities, it launches the app from beginning while i need it should be from existing activity. How is it possible?

Can anybody  help me on this ?

Regards
Gaurav

Comment: can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your testscript?
Are you using `driver.close()` somewhere in code i.e. in `@AfterTest` , if so can you comment that out and try.

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup()
{
    //your setup logic
}

@Test
public void busiLogic()
{
    //business logic
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown()
{
    //dont put driver.close()
}
```

This is my assumption that you are closing the driver in your testscript code. please post your code. [Thanks](http://mylearningdiaree.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 0):

What it seems like is happening is you are using `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` when you should use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` instead.

They do what they say on the tin. If you initialise your `appiumDriver` in **`@BeforeTest`**, it will spin up a new session **before** every **test**. If you close/quit your session with `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` in **`AfterTest`** then **after** every **test** it will be torn down and won't be around for the next test.

Use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` instead.

You can setup a `@priority` system to ensure tests are completed in a certain order. [Documentation here](http://beust.com/weblog/2008/03/29/test-method-priorities-in-testng/).

Hope this helps,

Liam

Answer (score 0):

Please share your views on below code:

public class Test1 {

WebDriver dr;

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities;

@Test
public void testapp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {




    File app = new File("D:\\Appium_Automation\\abc.apk");
    capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","samsung-sm_n910g-641dd802");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","5.0.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("apppackage","com.sk.test");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.fp.test.test");
    dr = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}
```

public class Test2 {

```
@Test
public void method1() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {



    //Few line Code


}
```

public class Test3 {

```
@Test
public void method1() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {


    //Few line Code

}
```

First time, I run  2 classes (Test1 and Test2) and it  works' perfectly and complete the suite. And script status is pass.

Second Time or running the 2nd suite, I want to run Test3 class so it require to run Class "Test1" but i want application should not be relaunch and it should comes in foreground with the previously opened activity.

Please tell me what changes should be done in Class Test1 at 2nd time run or required any changes in appium settimng.I am using "No Reset" option

Answer (score 0):

```
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.fp.test.test");
```

This is happen due to each time you launching your app with this activity and probability is like this is first activity ( Login screen) from your app whenever you request the app it will open with login screen for the same try to find the activity which after the first / login activity for that you can use this app `'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intelloware.apkinfo&hl=en'`